# Why is my user object missing from the req object?

Tags: angular, mongoose

The following function, UserService.signIn(), makes a call to the server to sign in a user:

UserService.signIn():

```
public signIn(credentials) {
    let body = JSON.stringify(credentials);

    return this.httpClient.post(this.userUrl, body, httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      map(token => {
        this.cartService.getCart().subscribe();
      }),
      catchError(this.handleError.bind(this))
    )    
  }
```

The server's signIn function stores the user object on the req object as shown: req.user = user. req.user is logged to the console and shows the expected value.

user.server.controller#signIn()

```
exports.signin = function(req, res) {
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;

    User.findOne({
        email:email
    }).exec(function(err, user) {
        if(err) {      
        } else if(user == null) { 
            }else {
                if(bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password)) {
                    console.log('user found', user)
                    var token = jwt.sign({name:user.name, email:user.email}, 
                        config.sessionSecret, {expiresIn:3600});
                    req.user = user;
                    console.log('\nuser.server.controller#req.user', req.user)
                    res.status(200).json(token);
                   return;
                } else {
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Upon return of UserService.signIn() shown above, within the map method, it calls CartService.getCart() to retrieve the user's cart as shown:

```
 map(token => {
    this.cartService.getCart().subscribe();
 }),
```

CartService.getCart() then makes a call to the server to retrieve the user's cart as shown:

```
public getCart() {
    return this.httpClient.get(this.cartUrl)
    .pipe(
      tap(cart => this.logger.log('cart', cart))
    )
 }
```

In cart.server.controller#getCart(), I try to use the email of req.user that was previously saved to the req object during the previous call to user.server.controller#signIn() but I get an error that req.user is undefined.

cart.server.controller#getCart()

```
exports.getCart = function (req, res) {
    Cart.findOne({
        email: req.user.email
    }).exec(function (err, cart) {

    })
}
```

Comment: What version of Angular are you using?

Comment: Angular version 6.1.9

Answer (score 0):

You had defined the `getCart` method having two arguments req and res however whenever you are calling the it, you are calling without any parameters. It means you had passed nothing.

You must pass call the method as -

```
this.cartService.getCart(req,res)
```

instead of

```
this.cartService.getCart()
```